# .net unit testing with generic abstract type parameter & chaining

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, testing, chaining

What would be the proper way to unit test an abstract class which takes generic type parameter where the type is also an abstract class?  E.g)

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseT { ... }
```

I'll have to create a test class which extends BaseT, right??

and what happen if the BaseClass support method chaining such that

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T> { ... } ??
```

thanks.

updated concrete class sample for the 2nd case:

```
    public class ConcreteClass : BaseClass<ConcreteClass>
    {
        public ConcreteClass Method1()
        {
            return this as ConcreteClass;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without implementing a dummy implementation class using Rhino Mocks: http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx

Unfortunately, Rhino Mocks requires you to use the record/playback syntax with partial mocks instead of the AAA syntax.

Given the following abstract classes:

```
public abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public abstract int Increment();
}

public abstract class AbstractClass<T> where T : BaseAbstract
{
    private int inc;

    public abstract T Abstract();

    public virtual int Concrete()
    {
        return inc += Abstract().Increment();
    }
}
```

You can test the implementation of Concrete in the following way:

```
[Test]
public void mock_an_abstract_class_with_generic()
{
    var mocks = new MockRepository();
    var baseAbstract = mocks.StrictMock<BaseAbstract>();
    var abstractClass = mocks.PartialMock<AbstractClass<BaseAbstract>>();

    using (mocks.Record())
    {
        baseAbstract.Stub(a => a.Increment()).Return(5);
        abstractClass.Stub(a => a.Abstract()).Return(baseAbstract);
    }

    using (mocks.Playback())
    {
        abstractClass.Concrete().ShouldEqual(5);
        abstractClass.Concrete().ShouldEqual(10);
    }
}
```

In essence, you create a partial mock for the base class, set expectations on the abstract methods, then call the concrete method under test. The generic is simply another mock, another partial if necessary.

The downside of this is obviously the requirement for the record/playback syntax. I don't know if other mocking frameworks can help you out more here, but I've generally found that Rhino Mocks is the mocking framework you go to if you have an advanced use case like this.

Comment: I see what you're saying - yeah, that's a lot trickier. I'm going to mess around with this now, but I feel like you're going to be stuck creating a dummy concrete class to test with.

Comment: I just realized, can you provide an example of a concrete implementation of public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>? Unless I'm being dense, I don't think it's possible to provide a concrete implementation of that class signature.

Comment: I updated the example to include generics. I finally figured out what you mean by the second example (public class ImplementingClass : BaseClass<ImplementingClass>). I'm going to mess around with that when I have some more free time, but hopefully it's essentially the same solution.

Comment: I can't figure out for the life of me how to mock the method-chaining generic restriction. I even tried diving into heavy reflection, and it just turns out too complicated. I think for that structure, you're stuck implementing a dummy class. It's easier than anything else I was able to come up with. Maybe someone else will come up with a clever way to facilitate that.

Comment: thanks alot mrdowns, I'm using the Moq framework right now.  Looks like i'll be stuck by creating a dummy concrete class for the 2nd case.  Anyhow, updated sample above..

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details, I'm guessing that you are trying to test some code that is implemented in the abstract generic class. For example, you might test a public method or property that is implemented in the base class and isn't marked as abstract.

So, you will have to create a class that extends the generic base class BaseClass< T >
and a different class that extends BaseT.   Let's call these ConcreteClass< T > and ConcreteT respectively.

Then, instantiate a class of type ConcreteClass< ConcreteT >.   You can now run tests on this instance, allowing you to test the abstract class' logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to test an abstract class, you cannot create an instance of :)

Comment: Well, you can create a helper class that inherits it.  With that in mind, do you have an actual answer for the OP, or is this just a comment?

Comment: It will not be the same thing, will it? If it is abstract, it has some abstract methods so needs implementataion. I do not believe there is a way...

Comment: Without the generic type parameters, it can be tested by mocking them.

Comment: Mocking what you are trying to test?